# Problem with @test a java sorting program

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, testing

I did a sort method for sorting array in ascendent order:

```
public class Sorting {
    public void sort(int[] array) {

        if (Objects.isNull(array)) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();

        } else {
            Arrays.sort(array);
            System.out.println(array);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a SortingTest class:

```
public class SortingTest {

    Sorting sorting = new Sorting();

    @Test
    public void testNullCase() {
        int [] expected = null;
int [] actual = null;
        assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);

}
}
```

and I test and `testEmptyCase()`, `testSingleElementArrayCase()`, `public void testSortedArraysCase()` and `testOtherCases()`.
I test my program for sorting an array, but for below @test methods failure. How to do the test right? I want to understand what I need to do do what in the test is expected. Thanks for help.

```
@Test
    public void testNullCarelessSorting() {
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.run(NullCarelessSortingTestExtension.class);

        assertEquals(1, result.getFailureCount());
        assertEquals(5, result.getRunCount());

        Failure nullCaseFailure = null;
        
    }

@Test
    public void testLazySorting() {
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.run(LazySortingTestExtension.class);

        assertEquals(2, result.getFailureCount());
        assertEquals(5, result.getRunCount());

        Failure nullCaseFailure = null;
        Failure otherCasesFailure = null;
        
    }
@Test
    public void testTrickySorting() {
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.run(TrickySortingTestExtension.class);

        assertEquals(4, result.getFailureCount());
        assertEquals(5, result.getRunCount());

        Failure emptyCaseFailure = null;
        Failure singleCaseFailure = null;
        Failure sortedCaseFailure = null;
        Failure otherCasesFailure = null;
           
}
```

Comment: Why did you use nested `do-while` loop?  Variable `i` is not changed inside this loop therefore all user inputs are stored at the same index `n[i] = scanner.nextInt()` until user inputs `0`.

Comment: how did you test other cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop needs some correction as shown below:

```
public class Average
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int ARRAY_SIZE = 100;
        int[] n = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println("Input: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {

            int a = scanner.nextInt();
            n[i] = a;
            sum += n[i];
            count++;
            if (a == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count <= 1 ? "Output : " + (sum) : "Output : " + (sum / (count - 1)));
    }
}
```

What was happening in your logic is that the first index (0) keeps repeating as there is another do-while loop inside your main for loop which keeps consuming your scanner inputs.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Thats true. Updated with the condition to handle that.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if you are sorted. Thanks.